# JavaFX 2 Line on Pane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I would like to add a line inside a Pane but the line is not shown when I run the application.
Adding a Label with an ImageView inside my Pane is working, I can see the image I'm setting on the ImageView.  I tried to show a Line in several ways, using Canvas, drawing a line and adding the Canvas to the Pane, also building a Line and adding it directly to the Pane, none are working.

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
//Image image = new Image("image.png");
//ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
//imageView.setImage(image);
//Label label = new Label();
//label.setGraphic(imageView);
//Canvas canvas = new Canvas(105, 105);
//canvas.relocate(296, 128);
//GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
//gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
//gc.setLineWidth(5);
//gc.strokeLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
Line redLine = LineBuilder.create()
                        .startX(296)
                        .startY(128)
                        .endX(401)
                        .endY(233)
                        .fill(Color.RED)
                        .strokeWidth(10.0f)
                        .build();
pane.getChildren().add(redLine);
//pane.getChildren().add(canvas);
//pane.getChildren().addAll(label, redLine);
```

Comment: what do you mean with "not working" ? when I copypaste your code, it works for me (a line is shown, though a black one)

Comment: Yes, and I have a black background, that is why I didn't see the Line.  Have to set the attribute stroke to have the line painted with the wanted color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted seems functional - Here's the result I got:

[image: Screenshot of Program with Line]

And here's the code I used:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class FXLine extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Line redLine = LineBuilder.create()
            .startX(296)
            .startY(128)
            .endX(401)
            .endY(233)
            .fill(Color.RED)
            .strokeWidth(10.0f)
            .build();
        pane.getChildren().add(redLine);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 425, 275));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```